# C++ boost::archive::archive_exception: input stream error while serializing OpenCV object

Tags: c++, opencv, serialization, boost, zeromq

Hello I've using text_oarchive to send serialized opencv mat objects to another computer which was working well after I noticed it is slow I wanted to change to binary_oarchive which gives me error I've wrote in title

here is my header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(cv::Mat)
namespace boost {
    namespace serialization {

        /*** Mat ***/
        template<class Archive>
        void save(Archive & ar, const cv::Mat& m, const unsigned int version)
        {
            size_t elemSize = m.elemSize(), elemType = m.type();

            ar & m.cols;
            ar & m.rows;
            ar & elemSize;
            ar & elemType; // element type.
            size_t dataSize = m.cols * m.rows * m.elemSize();

            //cout << "Writing matrix data rows, cols, elemSize, type, datasize: (" << m.rows << "," << m.cols << "," << m.elemSize() << "," << m.type() << "," << dataSize << ")" << endl;

            for (size_t dc = 0; dc < dataSize; ++dc) {
                ar & m.data[dc];
            }
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void load(Archive & ar, cv::Mat& m, const unsigned int version)
        {
            int cols, rows;
            size_t elemSize, elemType;

            ar & cols;
            ar & rows;
            ar & elemSize;
            ar & elemType;

            m.create(rows, cols, elemType);
            size_t dataSize = m.cols * m.rows * elemSize;

            //cout << "reading matrix data rows, cols, elemSize, type, datasize: (" << m.rows << "," << m.cols << "," << m.elemSize() << "," << m.type() << "," << dataSize << ")" << endl;

            for (size_t dc = 0; dc < dataSize; ++dc) {
                ar & m.data[dc];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is my load function

```
void load(cv::Mat & mat, const char * data_str)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << data_str;

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive tia(ss);
    tia >> mat;
}
```

and this is my save function

```
std::string save(const cv::Mat &mat) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive toa(oss);
    toa << mat;

    return oss.str().data();
}
```